# How to get the type of a field via Javascript : Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

How do I get the field type of a field in Google App Maker?

I have tried to find it via:

app.models.MODEL_NAME.fields.date

but there isn't a property type for a field.

So the question is how can I find the type of a field via Javascript?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is how I do it; Suppose I want to know what are all the field types of a model. I use this:

```
var allFields = app.models.MODEL_NAME.fields._values;
for( var f=0; f<allFields.length; f++) {
  var field = allFields[f];  
  var fieldType = field.__gwt_instance.b.B.j;
  console.log(fieldType);
}
```

So, in summary, all you have to do is get the field:

```
var field = app.models.MODEL_NAME.fields.DESIRED_FIELD
```

Then you just get the type like this:

```
var fieldType = field.__gwt_instance.b.B.j;
```

As I say, this works for me. I hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a less cryptic attribute that will give you the field type (although it only works in server scripts):

```
app.metadata.models.MODEL_NAME.fields.DESIRED_FIELD.type;
```